# Magento 2 : How to change customer account page title

Tags: magento2, customer-account, dashboard, page-title

[image]

Hi, I have created custom theme. I want change account page title from "My Dashboard" to loggedin customer name. How I can do this.

Although I have found file customer_account_index.xml that is setting title. But no idea how to make dynamic.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<update handle="customer_account"/>
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
        <action method="setPageTitle">
            <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">My Dashboard</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="customer_account_dashboard_top" as="top"/>
        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info" name="customer_account_dashboard_info" as="info" template="account/dashboard/info.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Address" name="customer_account_dashboard_address" as="address" template="account/dashboard/address.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Thanks in advanced!!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also use this below code.

**customer_account_index.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<update handle="customer_account"/>
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" template="Vendor_Module::template.phtml">
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

**template.phtml**

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()):
?>
<h1 class="page-title">
    <span class="base" data-ui-id="page-title-wrapper"><?php echo($customerSession->getCustomer()->getName()); ?></span>
</h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 5):

In  this case, we can use `layout_generate_blocks_before`

On this fire ***an observer which change title*** and set Current customer name in place of `My Dashboard`

### Observer:

```
<?php
namespace Devamitbera\ChangePagetitle\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class ObserverChangePagetitleForAccount implements ObserverInterface
{


    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag
     */
    protected $_actionFlag;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface
     */
    protected $messageManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface
     */
    protected $redirect;


    protected $_pageConfig;
    protected $customerSession;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag $actionFlag
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag $actionFlag,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect,
         \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config $pageConfig     
    ) {
        $this->_actionFlag = $actionFlag;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->redirect = $redirect;
        $this->_pageConfig = $pageConfig; 
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action $controller */
        $full_action_name = $observer->getFullActionName();

        $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();
        if($full_action_name == 'customer_account_index'){
            //print_r($layout->getBlock('head')->getRobots());
            //$this->_pageConfig->setRobots('NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW');

            $layout->getBlock('page.title')->setPageTitle($this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getName());
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to override `Magento/Customer/Controller/Account/Index.php`

It should be like,

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Module\Vendor\Controller\Account;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\AbstractAccount
{
    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    protected $customerSession;
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Default customer account page
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('My Account')); //for browser tab title
        $this->_view->getLayout()->getBlock('page.main.title')->setPageTitle($this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getName()); //dynamic user name as a title
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

I have tested it works!

Answer (score 1):

Please follow below steps

1) Find this file

```
root\app\design\frontend\Namespace\themeName\Magento_Customer\layout\customer_account_index.xml
```

=>> Please comment 'My Dashboard' title referenceBlock.

2) Then Find this file

```
root\app\design\frontend\Namespace\themeName\Magento_Customer\templates\account\dashboard\info.phtml
```

Put below 2 lines on top after php tag start:

```
$userNameObj = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$customerSession = $userNameObj->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
```

Then add below code after block 'block-dashboard-info' class div :

```
   <div class="page-title-wrapper">
        <h1 class="page-title">
    <?php if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
        $userName = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getName()."<br/>";  // get  Full Name ?>
            <span class="base" data-ui-id="page-title-wrapper">Welcome <?php echo $userName; ?></span>
            <?php 
          }  ?>
          </h1>
    </div>
```

Now, login from frontend it will display "Welcome user user".