# Setup SendFriend page title

Tags: magento2

Does anybody know true-way to setup SendFriend page title?

There is no default title in *vanilla* Magento 2. It is empty. 
In details: Magneto add title-suffix, if you are setup it before.

I suppose there are 2 methods only:

1. New Module (via XML)
2. Override title in themes templates

Note: title must be translatable.

Ex.: 
[image]

Comment: You can also do it using an observer. Check this answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/159834/magento-2-how-to-change-customer-account-page-title/159851#159851

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create **sendfriend_product_send.xml** under below path:

> app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[theme]/Magento_SendFriend/layout/sendfriend_product_send.xml

and add the below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Your custom title</title>
    </head> 
</page>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Will this be translatable?

Comment: Yes ofcourse. You can add text in csv file and it will translate in the same way as other does.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't sure if text included in the xml is translatable ;) I thought you had to use the __() function to achieve this :D Thanks

Comment: I have tested with translation and it works fine for me.